# Capture user click and typing in a custom WPF TextBox-like control?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

Trying to make an equation editor like that in Microsoft Word in C# and WPF.  XML cannot be used; it has to be purely programmatic.

Right now I have `LineGUIObject : System.Windows.Controls.WrapPanel`, which is like `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`, except that instead of just showing strings it shows each element of a `List<System.Windows.UIElement>` in order.

Now I want for a user to be able to click on an instance of `LineGUIObject` and type into it.  The holdup is that I don't know how to capture the user's click or read the input that they type.  How can this be done?

Note: This question is not asking how to handle input once captured; just how to get the input in the first place.  For example, is there some `event` that fires off after the user clicks it or something?  I can't seem to find one for `System.Windows.Controls.WrapPanel`, which might imply that I need to use another type of object, or..?

Current code:

```
public class LineGUIObject
    :   System.Windows.Controls.WrapPanel
{
    private List<System.Windows.UIElement> _uiElementList;
    private CursorGUIObject _cursor;
    private int? _cursorIndex;
    public LineGUIObject(System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher dispatcher)
        : base()
    {
        this.UIElementList = new List<System.Windows.UIElement>();
        this.Cursor = new CursorGUIObject(dispatcher, 25, 1.5, 250);
        this.UIElementList.Add(this.Cursor);

        this.AddText("[junk string just to see this otherwise invisible object while debugging]");
    }
    protected void InterpretUserKeyStroke(/* ??? */)
    {
        //How do we get this method to be called on user input,
        //e.g. when the user types "1"?
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected void AddText(string text)
    {
        this.UIElementList.Add(new System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock(new System.Windows.Documents.Run(text)));
        this.UpdateDisplay();
    }
    protected List<System.Windows.UIElement> UIElementList { get { return this._uiElementList; } private set { this._uiElementList = value; } }
    protected CursorGUIObject Cursor { get { return this._cursor; } private set { this._cursor = value; } }
    protected int? CursorIndex
    {
        get { return this._cursorIndex; }
        set
        {
            int? nullablePriorIndex = this.CursorIndex;

            if (nullablePriorIndex != null)
            {
                int priorIndex = nullablePriorIndex.Value;
                this.UIElementList.RemoveAt(priorIndex);
            }

            if (value == null)
            {
                this._cursorIndex = null;
            }
            else
            {
                int newIndex = value.Value;
                if (newIndex < 0)
                {
                    newIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    int thisListCount = this.UIElementList.Count;
                    if (newIndex > thisListCount) { newIndex = thisListCount; }
                }

                this.UIElementList.Insert(newIndex, this.Cursor);
                this._cursorIndex = newIndex;
            }

            this.UpdateDisplay();
        }
    }

    protected void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        this.Children.Clear();
        foreach (System.Windows.UIElement uiElement in this.UIElementList) { this.Children.Add(uiElement); }
    }
}


public class CursorGUIObject
    :   System.Windows.Controls.WrapPanel
{
    public const double MINIMUM_BLINK_TIME_IN_MS = 5;
    public const double MINIMUM_HEIGHT = 0.5;
    public const double MINIMUM_WIDTH = 0.5;

    private object ToggleVisibilityLock = new object();

    private delegate void TimerIntervalDelegate();

    private System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle _rectangle;
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher _dispatcher;
    public CursorGUIObject(System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher dispatcher, double height, double width, double blinkTimeInMS)
    {
        this.Dispatcher = dispatcher;

        System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
        rectangle.Width = width > MINIMUM_WIDTH ? width : MINIMUM_WIDTH;
        rectangle.Height = height > MINIMUM_HEIGHT ? height : MINIMUM_HEIGHT;
        rectangle.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        this.Rectangle = rectangle;
        this.Children.Add(rectangle);

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(blinkTimeInMS > MINIMUM_BLINK_TIME_IN_MS ? blinkTimeInMS : MINIMUM_BLINK_TIME_IN_MS);
        this.Timer = timer;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }
    ~CursorGUIObject()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = this.Timer;
        if (timer != null) { timer.Dispose(); }
    }
    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Delegate timerDelegate = new TimerIntervalDelegate(ToggleVisibility);
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(timerDelegate);
    }
    protected void ToggleVisibility()
    {
        lock (ToggleVisibilityLock)
        {
            if (this.Rectangle.Visibility.Equals(System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden))
            {
                this.Rectangle.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Rectangle.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
    }
    protected System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle Rectangle { get { return this._rectangle; } private set { this._rectangle = value; } }
    protected System.Timers.Timer Timer { get { return this._timer; } private set { this._timer = value; } }
    protected System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher Dispatcher { get { return this._dispatcher; } private set { this._dispatcher = value; } }
}
```

Comment: My current best guess is that I should just have `MainWindow` capture all user input and direct it to the appropriate GUI element myself.  (This doesn't answer the question, just where I'm currently at.)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much all WPF controls provide access to the [`UIElement.PreviewMouseDown` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown(v=vs.110).aspx), which you can use to monitor mouse clicks. So, this event lets you monitor when each object is clicked on. Next, I'd advise you to use a small `Popup` control to popup a `TextBox` that the user could enter a value with:

```
<Popup Name="Popup">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Padding="5">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding InputText}" />
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Depending on how you have set up your project, you *could* open the `Popup` from the event handler:

```
private void YourObject_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: +1: Thanks, I didn't even realize that there was a `Popup` control!  I can definitely see how this would allow a working solution for user input.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `LineGUIObject` just needed to have `this.Focusable = true;` set in its constructor so that it could receive the keyboard's focus when clicked.

Now that it can be focused on, `this.KeyUp += LineGUIObject_KeyUp;` also in the constructor, and

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.AddText(e.Key.ToString());
    }
```

Even this had a problem at first since my `LineGUIObject` was nested in a `ScrollViewer` which kept stealing focus immediately after the `LineGUIObject` would receive it.  This was fixed by making the `ScrollViewer` to be unable to get focus, i.e. `<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Focusable="False"/>`.

Comment: Perhaps they didn't like your solution, but I have to admit that it *is* annoying when people down vote without leaving a reason... in my opinion, that is completely pointless, as the down voted user has no idea why and what they could do to improve.